# Metaphor similar to "one apple spoils the whole bunch"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, metaphors, proverbs, simile

I am trying to describe sectarianism that starts from the oldest generation and seeps down to their children and grandchildren and I am getting major writer's block when trying to find a metaphorical way of describing this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Like "unto their children"?

Comment: "One rotten apple spoils the whole bunch" is a metaphor itself.

Comment: Yeah unto their children works, I'm just trying to think of a way to express that the younger generation often become polluted by the views of their elders.

Comment: @Centaurus I know I just thought it was too much of a cliche for this particular piece :)

Comment: That's another apple saw: the apple doesn't fall from the tree. Meaning we are somewhat like our parents.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, so then it must be: one spoiled apple doesn't fall far from the rotten tree ;)

Comment: " to express that the younger generation often become polluted by the views of their elders." sounds like _indoctrintion_.

Comment: I fail to see what the spoiled apple adage has to do with the described situation. (Unless it's meant as collective punishment based on familial ties?) The apple not falling far from the tree fits much better, if the context is that parents and children are very much alike in this (negative) attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some colloquial English phrases for 'a child acquiring its parents' characteristics or features'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/what-are-some-colloquial-english-phrases-for-a-child-acquiring-its-parents-cha) ( "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree", "like father, like son" ...)